# How to omit pages if error happens in Gatsby

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

How I can handle errors for failed page creation during the build process so that failed pages are just skipped instead of crashing the whole build?

Error happens on one page on: **Building static HTML for pages**

Comment: Why not fix the single page or remove it? The HTML build errors are there to help you put out a solid product.

Comment: well I'm using this as page publisher. Now one page error blocks others from publishing. If there is error this page will not publish (I should get 404) , but working pages should be published.